# Are domain sizes in typical magnets always limited by magnetostatic energy? Or can there be a significant Kibble-Zurek effect?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, magnetic-fields, solid-state-physics, material-science

Apparently, realistic ferromagnetic metals (e.g. pure iron) differ from Ising-like spin models in a number of ways. 
One of these is that realistic ferromagnets don't magnetize spontaneously, they form finite [domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_domain) instead so that the macroscopic magnetic field is minimized. This physics is entirely missed by the Ising model from studying renormalization, scale invariance... as the latter would predict true long-range order in the ground state/steady state.

However, also from such simple models, one could come up with entirely different arguments for why objects naturally have finite domains. Either originating from nature (astronomic or geological) or from its industrial fabrication, it seems most iron is produced above the Curie temperature after which it has been cooled down.

Now, as it passes the phase transition from paramagnetic to ferromagnetic at finite speed $v$, critical slowing down takes place, meaning that the correlation length is never able to diverge and spread over the whole system. This is known as the [Kibble-Zurek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibble%E2%80%93Zurek_mechanism)(KZ) mechanism and is known to lead to the formation of finite domains in the symmetry-broken phase. This is not an argument about the true steady state, but rather about long-living metastable states. I don't believe that this is inherently a problem for the argument, as the flipping time for large domains grows exponentially. 
Filling in 2D values for critical exponents in the formula on Wikipedia, a resulting domain size
$\overline{\xi}\sim v^{-1/3}$ would be expected.

Can we be sure that is always magnetostatic energy that sets the domain size in a magnet? Or are cases where the domain size actually follows from KZ possible under realistic circumstances?